# Bean of type 'java.lang.String' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am developing web client for github. I need to register web client as bean and have opportunity to specify baseUrl.

Code:

```
public class ClientConfiguration {

    private static final String GITHUB_BASE_URL = "https://api.github.com/";

    private final ApplicationConfig applicationConfig;

    @Autowired
    public ClientConfiguration(ApplicationConfig applicationConfig) {
        this.applicationConfig = applicationConfig;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public WebClient gitHubWebClient() {
        return WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl(GITHUB_BASE_URL)
                .defaultHeader("Accept", "application/vnd.github+json")
                .defaultHeader("X-GitHub-Api-Version", "2022-11-28")
                .defaultHeader("Authorization", String.format("Bearer %s", applicationConfig.gitHubToken()))
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebClient gitHubWebClientWithBaseUrl(String url) {
        return WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .defaultHeader("Accept", "application/vnd.github+json")
                .defaultHeader("X-GitHub-Api-Version", "2022-11-28")
                .defaultHeader("Authorization", String.format("Bearer %s", applicationConfig.gitHubToken()))
                .build();
    }

}
```

When I start the app, here is exception:

```
Parameter 0 of method gitHubWebClientWithBaseUrl in ru.example.edu.java.scrapper.configuration.ClientConfiguration required a bean of type 'java.lang.String' that could not be found.
```

Comment: Spring has no idea what it should pass as an input parameter of the method gitHubWebClientWithBaseUrl(String url). If it is a value from configuration, you can mark it with @Value annotation, like gitHubWebClientWithBaseUrl(@Value("${some.configuration.value}") String url)

Answer (score 0):

Spring f/w is not sure what to pass in as value for `url` this can be resolved by either defining a bean named `url` like below :

```java
   @Bean
    public String url() {
        return  "www.example.com";
    }

    @Bean
    public WebClient gitHubWebClientWithBaseUrl(String url) {
        return WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .build();
    }
```

**Or**

by adding your baseUrl value in `application.properties` like below

```
base.url=www.example.com
```

and editing your config class like below

```java
    @Bean
    public WebClient gitHubWebClientWithBaseUrl(@Value("${base.url}") String url) {
        return WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .build();
    }
```